# Session php para carrito de libros

Tags: php, sesiones

Buen día. Estoy programando un carrito de libros a partir de una base de datos de libros utilizando sesiones php. Falta muy poco para que funcione pero estoy atorado porque el carrito no recoge los libros agregados. No pongo los formularios completos solo los envíos para que sepan los datos que mando.

**El esquema es el siguiente**

sesión no iniciada-->buscar libros-->agregar libro (the_id)-->registrar email-->continuar búsqueda

sesión iniciada-->buscar libros-->agregar libro(the_id)-->mantenerse en resultados de búsqueda

**El usuario hace una búsqueda y le da click agregar libro, si no está registrado le pide agregar email para iniciar sesión, y envía id del libro (funciona)**

$the_id es el identificador del libro

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Tu email" name="usuario" required>
<input type="hidden" name="libro" value="<?php echo the_ID() ?>">  
<input type="Submit" value="Registrarse"
```

**agregar libro con sesion iniciada, envía id del libro**

$the_id es el identificador del libro

```
<input type="hidden" name="libro" value="<?php echo the_ID() ?>"> 
<input type="submit"  value="A&ntilde;adir a Mis Registros"
```

**Abro sesión**

```
session_start();
```

**Guardo email de usuario como identificador (funciona)**

```
if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){ 
$usuario = $_POST['usuario']; 
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario; 
}
```

**Si hay usuario en sesión le da la bienvenida (funciona)**

```
if($_SESSION['usuario'])  { echo "Bienvenido: " . $_SESSION['usuario'] . "";}
```

**Establezco nombre de la sesión**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["random"])) {
$_SESSION["random"] = rand(1,10); 
}
$randomNumber = $_SESSION["random"];
```

**Recupero y guardo el id del libro. (name libro en el form)**

```
if (isset($_POST['libro'])) { 
$id = $_POST['libro']; 
$_SESSION['libro'] = $id; 
}
```

**Ver Mis registros. Si hay sesión con libros agregados los muestra**

```
if($_SESSION["random"]){ 
echo $id;
] else {
echo 'no hay registros';
}
```

El problema está en que el carrito está vacío y por lo tanto muestra que no hay registros, lo que me hace suponer que si se registra la sesión pero no se recoge el id de los libros. Ya que tenga los libros enviaré los registros por email pero todavía no puedo avanzar hacia ello porque el carrito de registros está vacío!!

Alguien que pueda orientarme...? gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en primer lugar no hace falta que hagas esto:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["random"])) {
    $_SESSION["random"] = rand(1,10); 
}
$randomNumber = $_SESSION["random"];
```

Entiendo que eso lo haces para poner un nombre de referencia a la sesión, pero la sesion es única para cada usuario, no es necesario asignarla una id.

Y en este trozo de código, lo que haces es... que si existe el valor "random" dentro de la sesion (que si existe), muestre a $id, la cual has definido mas arriba AL GUARDA EL LIBRO, con lo cual esa $id está vacía, deberías usar "*$_SESSION['libro']*" en su lugar, no $id.

```
if($_SESSION["random"]){ 
    echo $id;
] else {
    echo 'no hay registros';
}
```

Por otro lado, aparte de que no recuperas bien el dato libro guardado (id), tambien estas guardando mal el libro.

```
if (isset($_POST['libro'])) { 
    $id = $_POST['libro']; 
    $_SESSION['libro'] = $id; 
 }
```

Esta sentencia es correcta, funciona pero solo para guarda un libro, si te das cuenta, cuando haya un libro "1", por ejemplo y quieras guardar el libro "5", te repetirá esa sentencia, con lo cual $_SESSION['libro'] dejara de ser 1 y será 5, con lo cuál acabas de programar un "carrito" de libros donde solo puedes almacenar un libro.

**Lo que debes hacer** es guardar un array de ids, para asi hacer un carrito que guarde varios libros, comprobar si el libro ya esta en el array y si no, guardarle. Te pongo ejemplo cmabiando tu código:

```
//Antes de nada, debemos inicializar un array vacio, al loguearse un usuario
$_SESSION['libro'] = array();

//Y ya cada vez que enviemos un libro hacemos lo siguiente
if (isset($_POST['libro'])) {
    $id = $_POST['libro'];//Recojo la id

    //Comprobamos si esa id existe en nuestro array, si existe devuelve la 
    //posicion en la que esta y si no, un null, asi que mientras sea 
    //null, guardamos libro
    if(array_search($id, $_SESSION['libro']) == null){
        $_SESSION['libro'][] = $id;//Esta sentencia añade al final del array la nueva id
    }else{
        echo 'el libro ya esta en el carrito';
    }
 }
```

De esta manera, ya tenemos un carrito de verdad, que guarde varios libros, no solo uno como lo tenias tu antes, ahora solo falta recogerlo.

```
//Cuando quieras recoger los datos del carrito, hacemos un bucle for
//Y nos recogera cada id que haya en el array y la pintamos (o lo que sea)
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION['libro']); $i++){
    echo "Libro: " . $_SESSION['libro'][$i];
}
```

Espero que se entienda y que te ayude :)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tenía unos errores en mi código y no recuperaba bien el #id del libro que pasa a $_POST['libro'] pero ya lo logré solucionar por lo que ya pude probar el código que sugieres. El carrito múltiple, que efectivamente es el que me interesa, lamentablemente no funciona, pero el carrito de un libro si funciona. Para probar el carrito múltiple hice una comprobación de array y arrojó que está vacío lo que significa que no se guardan los libros en el carrito. Ahora intentaré averiguar por qué no se guardan...

Comment: Después de probar el código varias veces y revisar otros ejemplos, la solución para que tu código funcionase es que había que iniciar el array si no estaba iniciado  `if(!is_array($_SESSION['libro'])) //Si no es un array 
{
$_SESSION['libro'] = array();
} ` Gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: efectivamente, se me fué eso, inicié el array en una nueva variable, pero no en la sesión que es donde debería estar. Ahora si está todo bien, de nada :)